# MongoCursorException - Cursor not found (MongoDB PHP Driver)

Tags: php, mongodb, exception, cursor, timeout

**Code**:

```
try {
  $documentsFind = $client->$db->$collection->find([
      // query
  ]);
  if ($documentsFind) {
    foreach ($documentsFind as $product) {
    // code...
    }
  }
catch (MongoCursorException $e) {
  echo "error message: ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
  echo "error code: ".$e->getCode()."\n";
}
```

**Error**:

> Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException:
>   Cursor not found, cursor id: 31837896248 in ...

It seems that the cursor does exist but times out? How can I prevent that from happening?

**Edited to add**: I tried doing:

```
 if ($documentsFind) {
    $documentsFind->immortal(true); // keep alive
    foreach ($documentsFind as $product) {
    // code...
    }
  }
```

But that results in `Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::immortal()`.

Comment: Does the error appears on the first run or are you able to load some entries?

Comment: It fetches quite a few documents from the DB but times out at some point. I was able to bypass this temporarily with `mongod --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=9000000`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try querying like this:

```
$documentsFind = $client->$db->$collection->find([
  // query
], ['noCursorTimeout' => true]);
```

`find()` method passes the 2nd argument to the `Find` class constructor, so you can see all the available options [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Operation/Find.php#L31)

Answer (score 0):

[Cursor exception](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursorexception.php) says,

The driver was trying to fetch more results from the database, but the database did not have a record of the query. This usually means that the cursor timed out on the server side: after a few minutes of inactivity, the database will kill a cursor.

The MongoDB PHP driver has two different timeouts:

1. Connection timeout
2. Cursor timeout

Make sure you use timeout or immortal on the cursor:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->immortal(true); 
$cursor->timeout(-1);
```

Note: [Timeout](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php) indicates the time to wait on the client side while [immortal](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.immortal.php) sets the cursor on the server side.

But I would suggest if you have cursor of big data size then you should fetch cursor data in chunks like:

Get the first 1000 documents from collection, process them. Then get the next 1000 documents. You can do this by skip and limit.

Comment: Tried all of that. It appears that `immortal` and `timeout` are not available on the new PHP driver `mongodb`, not `mongo`.

Comment: Which mongodb version you are using? Are you getting cursor object for find()? Which php mongo driver you have? @3zzy